# CSS: Body border doesn't expand as middle div does?

Tags: css, border

I have a rule like this:

```
body{border:1px solid gray;}

#middle{
float:left;
margin-left:3%;
margin-top:20px;
width:41%;
border-top:solid #aaaaaa 1px;
}

.message-content{
padding:0 10px 0 10px;
float:left;
}
```

My HTML is like:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="middle">
  <div class="message-content">Loris ipsidum</div>
  <div class="message-content">Loris ipsidum</div>
<div id="clear"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to duplicate it in JSFiddle, but I wasn't able to.  Basically, what's happening is, after I get many message-content divs, the border defined by the `body` rule is passed.  It basically looks like there's a line right through the middle of the content.  Any ideas?

I'll try to get a working example up.

Comment: What is also strange is that I'm using PHP to load content into the `message-content` div, and the content doesn't appear in the source code, making this difficult to recreate.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `#middle` elements are floating, they don't count in the height of the parent (in this case the body), so the body is only taking up the height of the window.

You don't appear to have defined a `clear` style for your `#clear` element. Even so, the `clear` element should be *after*, not inside, the floating element.

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a way to have floating elements' heights factored in?

Comment: Clearing properly at the end should do it.

Comment: It didn't cause the border to expand, unfortunately.  I took away the border, which is better....